# Do we have to install new agent for every new host for Fleet

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I was currently exploring regarding elasticsearch fleet and I set up a basic fleet server and a enrolled an elastic-agent on one machine, for example, "machine-A" with a agent policy: "p1", Agent policy p1 is configured with one integration "system". I was able to collect it's logs on configured output.

Our requirement is to use integration for Barracauda Firewall. Fleet provides integration for this. My query is that in order to configure this, do I need to setup a separate agent on a separate machine and add provide a policy which includes Barracauda integration or I can use the current machine-A where already one elastic agent is running and update its policy to add Barracauda integration ?

While configuring Barracauda Firewall integration, it asks for certain parameters like ip, port etc.. details, so do I need to add Barracauda machine details there ?

Comment: Elastic agents usually need to be installed on the host they collect data from, but if Barracuda can also send logs via TCP/UDP, it is also possible to wire those logs to the Elastic agent installed on machine A and collect them from there as [shown here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/current/fleet-overview.html#elastic-agent)